# JSON_SET operation using Spring data relational Update fails with invalid json text

Tags: mysql, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-mysql

I am using R2dbc jasync driver to generate and execute update query on my mysql db table containing a json column.

I am trying to do a JSON_SET operation on a column using `R2dbcEntityTemplate` and `org.springframework.data.relational.core.query.Update.update` and `org.springframework.data.relational.core.query.Update.set` methods. I am trying to generate a query equivalent to
`UPDATE mytable SET json_col = JSON_SET(json_col, '$.path_to_update', CAST('{"a":"b"}' AS JSON)) WHERE id=:id`

But I get the following error:
`invalid json text: "the document is empty." at position 0 in value for column`

From what I understand is the `Update.set()` operation is not delegating the JSON_SET operation to the DB but the DB is trying to interpret the generated string as json which is not valid json at position 0.

How can I achieve this using `Update.set()` function to delegate the MySQL function call to the DB before DB interprets the value as JSON ?

I tried using `dbClient.sql().bind()` and it worked but using `dbTemplate.update()` this is not working.

Comment: use `CAST('{"a":"b"}' AS JSON)` not `TO JSON`

Comment: @aRvi my bad, that was a typing err. I've updated the question. The issue is still unresolved.